# If you partition a generating set of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ into finitely many pieces, are one of the parts a generating set?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, reference-request

If you partition a generating set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ (as a group) of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ into finitely many sets, $S_1,...,S_n$, are one of the parts a generating set? It is enough to study the case of $n=2$, since if it is true for 2, you will know that one of $S_1, S_2 \cup...\cup S_n$  is a generating set, if it isn't $S_1$ you know it is the other, so you can split that into $S_2, S_3 \cup...\cup S_n$. Now that I think about it, I would also be interested in the same question for the rationals.

I have been playing around/thinking about whether or not studying some (classes of)groups using some sort of infinite combinatorial method would be interesting, and figure I need an example group, like the reals, to generate good questions. In general I am interested in groups where every generating set partitioned into finitely many pieces has one of the pieces a generating set. Similarly I am interested in groups where you replace "generating set" with "normally generating set" in the previous sentence. (This is a "Ramseyan" condition for groups)

If these sorts of things have been studied, I would like some direction (like papers) of where to look. The idea to look into this is some set theoretic topology which studies combinatorics of open covers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, it can be expressed (assuming the axiom of choice) as a direct sum $V_1\oplus V_2$ of two proper subspaces. But then $V_1\cup V_2$ is a generating set, but neither $V_1$ nor $V_2$ is.

As for the rationals, you could take $S_1$ to be the set of rationals with denominator a power of $2$, and $S_2$ the set of rationals with odd denominator.